# The components aren't compiled to the .swc file for some reason!

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Hey folks I'm trying to compile an SWC file and everything works great until the part where it needs to add components, none of them added added to the .swc file at all.

The original file should be somewhere around 211 KB and when i compile it its only 1.64 KB, after unpacking the .swc and then the .swf inside it i can see that there is no components added at all.

BTW some components showing some errors but i dont think its a reason to not include ALL the components because the errors are like:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace.  XXX.as  /XXX/[source path] src/com/XXX  line 1469   Flex Problem
```

What could the problem be? ask me if you need some future info cause i don't really know what to include in here cause there is no code it's only a project with a library.

Best Regards,
Rico S.

Answer (score 1):

You jump around to a lot of issues in this question.

If you're receiving compiler errrors; then the SWC will not be generated at all.  So, first fix those compiler errors.

The error you mention sounds like a syntax error, with you did not properly close parenthesis.

In Flash Builder, you can open up the project properties, select Flex Library Build Path, select Classes, and then you can individually select the classes that should be added to your SWC.

Your question talks about original file size and compiled file size.  I'm not sure where "original file size" comes from.

Comment: Its some kind of open-source script my friend sent me and i can't find the source files so i just changed the .swc to .zip and then extracted the files from the .swf with Sothing SWF Decompiler. (Can the syntax errors be because it didn't extracts it properly?), BTW I'm not an .as genius is there any software that shows the errors on air? i mean like Dreamweaver does for HTML/PHP?

Comment: @Rico, *sigh*, really? Since when does a decompiler guarantees 100% working code?  Plus, you shouldn't decompile somebody's work.  If it's 'open-source', then the source should be somewhere on the net, not compiled in a swc...

Comment: @J_A_X - well i asked for help not for a legal suggestion, like i said i cant find the source and i want to solve this alone since it will give me some experience.

Comment: If you can't find the source, it's probably not open source. If you want to 'solve this by yourself', by all means go for it but stop asking us to commit copyright infringement on your behalf.

Comment: @Rico Steel If it is some kind of open source script, please tell us which one.  Perhaps we can help you find the source.